# ibm db2: insert strings into database in anonymous block

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I am trying to insert string data into a db2 table from an anonymous PL/SQL block.

What works;

```
SET SQLCOMPAT PLSQL;

BEGIN
...
SET ID_CITY = 0; SET city = chr(39) || 'Berlin' || chr(39); SET country_id = 83; SET REVNAME = chr(39) || 'create-script' || chr(39); SET REVCREATOR = chr(39) || 'create-script' || chr(39);
SET statement = 'INSERT INTO fk_city (ID_CITY, city, country_id, is_europe, REVNAME, REVDATE, REVFIRST, last_visit, REVCREATOR ) VALUES ( ' || ID_CITY || ', ' || city ||', ' || country_id || ', true, ' || REVNAME || ', CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, ' || REVCREATOR || ' )';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement;
...
END
```

My question is : Is there another way to insert into the table with a oneliner? For example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "INSERT INTO fk_city (ID_CITY, city, country_id, is_europe, REVNAME, REVDATE, REVFIRST, last_visit, REVCREATOR ) VALUES ( 0, 'Berlin', 83, true, 'create-script', CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, 'create-script' )";
```

The above statement throws an error SQL0107N ( name is too long ), which seems to have to do with the string delimiter ( " ) I used to embrace the statement

Comment: Why are you using a dynamic statement?

Comment: And why aren't you using bind variables?

Comment: The code is a part of a PHP script, which fires the statements against the database. How would bind variables solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the second statement with execute immediate replace Double quote with a quote at the beginning and at the end, and quotes in statement replace with two single quotes.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO fk_city (ID_CITY, city, country_id, is_europe, REVNAME, REVDATE, REVFIRST, last_visit, REVCREATOR ) VALUES ( 0, ''Berlin'', 83, ''true'', ''create-script'', CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, CURRENT DATE, ''create-script'' )';
```

I'm not sure what you mean in CURRENT DATE, maybe it should be some date time function like sysdate.

Comment: current date is a special register with the point of time the SQL statement started. Thank you for your help!